# Spring MVC controller ignored

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have started playing with Springboot and Spring MVC

I have had no problems, but now I am attempting to utilize security.

With the following pom, controller and curl request the curl request is completely ignored.

If I run with debug, with a stop point in the controller, it never gets there.
There are no error messages, but there are hundreds of lines of negative matches.

My controller does not show up under Mappings.

What do am I missing?

### pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>address-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>address-services</name>
    <description>REST services for address validation</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
            <skip_unit_tests>false</skip_unit_tests>
        <org.slf4j.version>1.7.28</org.slf4j.version>
        <org.xxx.version>9.2.0</org.xxx.version>
        <com.h2database.version>1.4.199</com.h2database.version>  
        <commons.lang.version>2.4</commons.lang.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.6</commons.io.version>
        <dom4j.version>1.6.1</dom4j.version>
        <!--  <org.springframework.version>5.2.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.version> -->
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!--  spring  -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- xxx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxx-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.xxx.version}</version>
    
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxx-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.xxx.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.xxx</groupId> <artifactId>xxx-hibernate</artifactId> 
            <version>${org.xxx.hibernate.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxx-jcmdline</artifactId>
            <version>${org.xxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxx-jcmdline</artifactId>
            <version>${org.xxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  others  -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### The controller

package org.xxx.address.service;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xxx.address.beans.AddressBean;
import org.xxx.address.beans.AddressList;
import org.xxx.address.service.usps.UspsAddressValidator;
import org.xxx.address.usps.AddressValidationException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@Controller
public class ValidationRest {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    
    public ValidationRest() {
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value="/validateAddress")
    public String validateAddress(
            @ModelAttribute String address1,
            @ModelAttribute String address2,
            @ModelAttribute String     city,
            @ModelAttribute String     state,
            @ModelAttribute String       zip,
            Model model) throws AddressValidationException {
        AddressBean address = new AddressBean(address1,address2,city,state,zip);
        List<AddressBean> list = new ArrayList<AddressBean>();
        list.add(address);
        UspsAddressValidator validator = new UspsAddressValidator();
         List<AddressBean> response = null;
        try {
            response = validator.validate(list);
        } catch (AddressValidationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        model.addAttribute("response",response);
        return "validatedAddress";
    }
```

### curl

echo rooter > curl -u root -X POST 
localhost:8080/validateAddress/&address1=410SouthMain&address2=&city=Romeo&state=MI&zip=78723

### stdout/stderr

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.0)

INFO  - 11:55:02,777 AddressApplication - Starting AddressApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 14.0.2 on atx with PID 2737903 (/home/jjs/git/diamond-21-windoze/javautil/address-services/target/address-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by jjs in /home/jjs/git/diamond-21-windoze/javautil/address-services)
INFO  - 11:55:02,777 AddressApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Jun 09, 2021 11:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jun 09, 2021 11:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
Jun 09, 2021 11:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO  - 11:55:04,220 AddressApplication - Started AddressApplication in 1.74 seconds (JVM running for 2.089)

Negative matches:
-----------------

   ActiveMQAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)

   ArtemisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   continues for hundreds of lines.
```

### Mappings

```
DEBUG Mappings - 
    o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryController:
    {OPTIONS [/ || ], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: optionsForRepositories()
    {HEAD [/ || ], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: headForRepositories()
    {GET [/ || ], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: listRepositories()
DEBUG Mappings - 
    o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryEntityController:
    {POST [/{repository}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: postCollectionResource(RootResourceInformation,PersistentEntityResource,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,String)
    {OPTIONS [/{repository}/{id}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: optionsForItemResource(RootResourceInformation)
    {HEAD [/{repository}/{id}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: headForItemResource(RootResourceInformation,Serializable,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
    {GET [/{repository}/{id}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: getItemResource(RootResourceInformation,Serializable,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,HttpHeaders)
    {PUT [/{repository}/{id}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: putItemResource(RootResourceInformation,PersistentEntityResource,Serializable,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,ETag,String)
    {PATCH [/{repository}/{id}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: patchItemResource(RootResourceInformation,PersistentEntityResource,Serializable,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,ETag,String)
    {DELETE [/{repository}/{id}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: deleteItemResource(RootResourceInformation,Serializable,ETag)
    {OPTIONS [/{repository}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: optionsForCollectionResource(RootResourceInformation)
    {HEAD [/{repository}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: headCollectionResource(RootResourceInformation,DefaultedPageable)
    {GET [/{repository}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: getCollectionResource(RootResourceInformation,DefaultedPageable,Sort,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
    {GET [/{repository}], produces [application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}: getCollectionResourceCompact(RootResourceInformation,DefaultedPageable,Sort,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
DEBUG Mappings - 
    o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController:
    {GET [/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: followPropertyReference(RootResourceInformation,Serializable,String,String,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
    {GET [/{repository}/{id}/{property}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: followPropertyReference(RootResourceInformation,Serializable,String,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
    {DELETE [/{repository}/{id}/{property}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: deletePropertyReference(RootResourceInformation,Serializable,String)
    {GET [/{repository}/{id}/{property}], produces [text/uri-list]}: followPropertyReferenceCompact(RootResourceInformation,Serializable,String,HttpHeaders,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
    {[PATCH, PUT, POST] [/{repository}/{id}/{property}], consumes [application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: createPropertyReference(RootResourceInformation,HttpMethod,CollectionModel,Serializable,String)
    {DELETE [/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: deletePropertyReferenceId(RootResourceInformation,Serializable,String,String)
DEBUG Mappings - 
    o.s.d.r.w.RepositorySearchController:
    {OPTIONS [/{repository}/search], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: optionsForSearches(RootResourceInformation)
    {HEAD [/{repository}/search], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: headForSearches(RootResourceInformation)
    {GET [/{repository}/search], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: listSearches(RootResourceInformation)
    {GET [/{repository}/search/{search}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: executeSearch(RootResourceInformation,MultiValueMap,String,DefaultedPageable,Sort,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,HttpHeaders)
    {GET [/{repository}/search/{search}], produces [application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}: executeSearchCompact(RootResourceInformation,HttpHeaders,MultiValueMap,String,String,DefaultedPageable,Sort,PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
    {OPTIONS [/{repository}/search/{search}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: optionsForSearch(RootResourceInformation,String)
    {HEAD [/{repository}/search/{search}], produces [application/hal+json || application/json || application/prs.hal-forms+json]}: headForSearch(RootResourceInformation,String)
DEBUG RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - 27 mappings in org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping
DEBUG Mappings - 
    o.s.d.r.w.RepositorySchemaController:
    {GET [/profile/{repository}], produces [application/schema+json]}: schema(RootResourceInformation)
DEBUG Mappings - 
    o.s.d.r.w.a.AlpsController:
    {GET [/profile/{repository}], produces [application/alps+json || */*]}: descriptor(RootResourceInformation)
    {OPTIONS [/profile/{repository}], produces [application/alps+json]}: alpsOptions()
DEBUG Mappings - 
    o.s.d.r.w.ProfileController:
    {OPTIONS [/profile]}: profileOptions()
    {GET [/profile]}: listAllFormsOfMetadata()
```

Comment: If you only want to debug security, you could use: `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` in your application.properties. Please provide use your security-configuration.  A blind guess: you are doing a post and csrf protection is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

From Mapping logs, it looks like that the data rest dependency what you had is not clearly cleaned up from your project.

I think trying to re-import the project should fix the issue.
Also, You should use `curl` like:

```
curl -d "address1=410SouthMain&address2=&city=Romeo&state=MI&zip=78723" -X POST http://localhost:8080/validateAddress
```

Comment: Always remember to do `mvn clean compile` when you change the dependencies in the pom